# How to order points anti clockwise

Tags: sorting, wolfram-mathematica

Lets take thess points.

```
pt={{-4.65371,0.1},{-4.68489,0.103169},{-4.78341,0.104834},{-4.83897,0.100757},
{-4.92102,0.0949725},{-4.93456,0.100181},{-4.89166,0.122666},{-4.78298,0.129514}, 
{-4.72723,0.121442},{-4.68355,0.11023},{-4.65371,0.1},{-4.66924,0.10173}, 
{-4.93059,0.0966989},{-4.93259,0.105094},{-4.91074,0.116966},{-4.90635,0.094878}, 
{-4.66846,0.105327},{-4.92647,0.0956182},{-4.93433,0.102498},{-4.9333,0.0982262},
{-4.66257,0.10102}};
```

Now they are in certain order (for me is a disorder!) which can be seen if we look at the `ListLinePLot`

```
picUnorder=ListLinePlot[pt,Frame-> True,Mesh-> All,MeshStyle-> PointSize[Large]];
SeepicUnorder=ListLinePlot[pt,Frame-> True,Mesh-> All,MeshStyle-> 
PointSize[Large]]/.Line[rest_]:>{Arrowheads[Table[0.02,{i,0,1,.02}]],Arrow[rest]};
GraphicsGrid[{{picUnorder,SeepicUnorder}}]
```

[image]

But we need to order them like the picture below.

[image]

Does anybody has some suggestion for a algorithm to sort such 2D points in counter clockwise direction so that we can rearrange the list of points to create a geometry like the last pic just by using `ListLinePlot` on the rearranged points????

Using the **suggestion** we get something like the following.

```
center=Mean[pt];
pts=SortBy[pt,Function[p,{x,y}=p-center;ArcTan[x,y]]];
Show[ListPlot[pt],ListLinePlot[pts,Mesh-> All,MeshStyle->
PointSize[Large]],Frame-> True]
```

[image]

BR

Comment: "clockwise" needs a center and a space orientation ... the problem is the center ...

Comment: Thanks @belisarius I will try my best to follow the suggestions. By the way do you think the answer with `FindShortestTour` is valid for general concave cluster of points?

Comment: no, but I don't think you'll find a _general_ solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just read in a comment to [nikie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673492/how-to-order-points-anti-clockwise/7673574#7673574) that what you really want is the algorithm for an airfoil. So, I am posting another (unrelated) answer to this problem:

[image]

Seems easier than the general problem, because it is "almost convex". I think the following algorithm reduce the risks that FindShortestTour inherently has at the acute vertex:

> 1. Find the `ConvexHull` (that accounts for the upper and attack surfaces)
> 2. Remove from the set the points in the convex hull
> 3. Perform a `FindShortestTour` with the remaining points
> 4. Join both curves at the nearest endpoints
> 5. Voilà

Like this:

```
pt1 = Union@pt;
<< ComputationalGeometry`
convexhull = ConvexHull[pt1, AllPoints -> True];
pt2 = pt1[[convexhull]];
pt3 = Complement[pt1, pt2];
pt4 = pt3[[(FindShortestTour@pt3)[[2]]]];
If[Norm[Last@pt4 - First@pt2] > Norm[Last@pt4 - Last@pt2], pt4 = Reverse@pt4];
pt5 = Join[pt4, pt2, {pt4[[1]]}];
Graphics[{Arrowheads[.02], Arrow@Partition[pt5, 2, 1], 
          Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@pt1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I posted the following  comment below your question: `I don't think you'll find a general solution`.  This answer tries to dig a little on that.

Heike's solution seems fair, but `FindShortestTour` is based on the metric properties of the set, while your requirement is probably more on the topological side.

Here is a comparison on two points sets and the methods available to  `FindShortestTour`:

```
pl[method_, k_] :=
  Module[{ptsorted, pt,s},
   little[x_] := {{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 1}}/x - (1/x) + 2;
   pt = Join[{{0, 0}, {4, 4}, {4, 0}, {0, 4}}, little[k]];
   ptsorted = Join[s = pt[[FindShortestTour[pt,Method->method][[2]]]], {s[[1]]}];
   ListPlot[ptsorted, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
                      PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
                      PlotRange -> {{-1, 5}, {-1, 5}}, 
                      Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLabel -> method]];
GraphicsGrid@
 Table[pl[i, j],
       {i, {"AllTours", "CCA", "Greedy", "GreedyCycle", 
            "IntegerLinearProgramming", "OrOpt", "OrZweig", "RemoveCrossings",
            "SpaceFillingCurve", "SimulatedAnnealing", "TwoOpt"}}, 
       {j, {1, 1.8}}]
```

## Fat Star         Slim Star

[image]

As you can see, several methods deliver the expected result on the left column, while only one does it on the right one. Moreover, the only useful method for the set on the right is completely off for the column on the left.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you could do something with `FindShortestTour`. For example

```
ptsorted = pt[[FindShortestTour[pt][[2]]]];
ListPlot[ptsorted, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

produces something like

[image: plot of shortest tour]

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you just sort the points?:

```
center = Mean[pt];
pts = SortBy[pt, Function[p, {x, y} = p - center; ArcTan[x, y]]]
Show[ListPlot[pt], ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True]]
```

Note that the polygon in your last plot is concave, so the points are not ordered clockwise!

Comment: It is still not the formation I want after sorting. It is not like the last pic of my post. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: @PlatoManiac: That's what I've been trying to tell you with the last sentence: The plot you showed is *not* clockwise. What kind of ordering *do* you want? What do you need this for?

Comment: Look at this simply by taking the right most point and then order the rest of the points not clock wise but anticlockwise and come back to the right most point. This forms a closed loop by starting with the right most point and ending at the same point. I need to order this points to for a 2D airfoil. http://enda1312.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/airfoil.gif

Comment: @PlatoManiac: The polygon you want is concave. It has inflection points. It's clockwise at some points, counterclockwise at others.

Comment: You are exactly right. Actually it seems no general solution to this problem exists. Sometimes your solution may work and sometimes not.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a python function which orders points counterclockwise. It Graham's Scan theorem. I've written it because I misunderstood a homework. It needs optimizing,though.

```
def order(a):
from math import atan2
arctangents=[]
arctangentsandpoints=[]
arctangentsoriginalsandpoints=[]
arctangentoriginals=[]
centerx=0
centery=0
sortedlist=[]
firstpoint=[]
k=len(a)
for i in a:
    x,y=i[0],i[1]
    centerx+=float(x)/float(k)
    centery+=float(y)/float(k)
for i in a:
    x,y=i[0],i[1]
    arctangentsandpoints+=[[i,atan2(y-centery,x-centerx)]]
    arctangents+=[atan2(y-centery,x-centerx)]
    arctangentsoriginalsandpoints+=[[i,atan2(y,x)]]
    arctangentoriginals+=[atan2(y,x)]
arctangents=sorted(arctangents)
arctangentoriginals=sorted(arctangentoriginals)
for i in arctangents:
    for c in arctangentsandpoints:
        if i==c[1]:
            sortedlist+=[c[0]]
for i in arctangentsoriginalsandpoints:
    if arctangentoriginals[0]==i[1]:
        firstpoint=i[0]
z=sortedlist.index(firstpoint)
m=sortedlist[:z]
sortedlist=sortedlist[z:]
sortedlist.extend(m)
return sortedlist
```